# Problem with `rake test`… rake reports "Could not find task ./test/whatever-my-first-test-file-is.rb"

Tags: ruby, rake

I've put this information into a pastie, but repeated it here (pastie link http://pastie.org/private/4vprzwhllqv35egrf8jzwg )

The problem showed up in my own project, but I have no idea what i'm doing wrong: here's the full output:

```
$ rake test

(in /Users/me/Projects/version-three)
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "./test/test_a.rb" "./test/test_configuration.rb" "./test/test_generator_base.rb" "./test/test_lazy_attr_accessor.rb" "./test/test_output_spokesman.rb" "./test/test_path_for_executable.rb" 
Test run options: --seed 28629

Loaded suite /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started

...............Could not find task "./test/test_a.rb".
......

Finished in 0.014943 seconds.

21 tests, 19 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Test run options: --seed 28629
```

As you can see there is an erroneous `Could not find task "./test/test_a.rb"` - I added this file simply to stop it choking on my first file with important tests!

The Rakefile couldn't be simpler, just this:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

task :default => :test

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['./test/test_*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

I'm using the following versions of relevant tools, as you can see I'm using RVM and I see the same problem on Ruby 1.8.7.

```
$ rake --version
  rake, version 0.8.7

$ ruby --version
  ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-11 revision 28618) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]

$ rvm --version
  rvm 0.1.43 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Comment: That's odd. Even though your snippet is exactly how it is in the docs. I would try omitting the line `t.libs << "test"` and let it default to the `lib` dir.

Comment: Unless there's something weird going on with your code elsewhere.

Comment: Blaine, if I remove all custom options and rely on the defaults, I have the exact same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this problem comes up when requiring `Thor` - it's a rake replacement, supposedly - perhaps I need to look into it more, but one of my tests was testing a Thor backed generator.

<strike>I'll look into what's going on more thoroughly!</strike>

I have identified the (foolish) problem, the message is actually coming out of Thor, I had a line that read like:

```
  def test_banner_if_starting_generator_with_no_args
    ::Cli::Generator.start(ARGV)
    # Test the banner output here...
  end
```

And of course `ARGV` was being set to the first file in the list assembled by Rake's FileList and passed to the test loader.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time who looked into this.

Solution: stub the `ARGV` to `[]` since that's effectively what I'm testing!